# escape velocity of the Milky Way galaxy

Tags: escape-velocity

I have heard of the escape velocity of Earth to be 11 km/s.

Is there an escape velocity of the Milky Way galaxy? If yes, what number is it and how can it be computed? Is there a difference in leaving vertically or horizontally?

Thank you.

Comment: Hello Jane,  The escape velocity of the galaxy is about 540 km/s (from the vicinity of the sun) This is explained and expanded upon in the question and answers I've linked to above.